# Difference between 'I got it' and 'you got it'?

Tags: phrase-usage, american-english

Logically, 'I got it' should mean 'I understand you'. But in many conversations I heard people say you got it and based on the context it seems they want to say 'I understood'.

I am confused when I should say either.

Comment: duplicate of https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101046/you-got-it-vs-i-got-it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***I got it*** means "I understand", this is correct. It can also be an expression of success in certain situations - that you got a job, for example, or even just an abbreviation of "I have got it", which can mean the same as "I have it".

***You got it*** as a *question* means "do you understand", but as a statement it's a response to a request, being asked to do something. It's an agreement to do whatever one has been asked to do - usually a particularly affirmative agreement.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct "I got it" means: I understood

whereas "you got it" means something else completely (that I knew), I just had to check google to find out what it does mean: your request will be carried out.

Think of it as person 1 saying "can you get me a ball" and person 2 wants to show person 1 how keen and eager and quick they are replying "you got it" to say "it is like it has already been done".

This has already been answered over on [English stack exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101046/you-got-it-vs-i-got-it)